# MKMapView cornerRadius only works for upper left corner

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, mapkit, mkmapview

i added a cornerRadius to layer of MKMapView something like

```
[self.routeMapView layer].cornerRadius = 20.0f;
```

this property effects only for upper left corner. Rest is not changed at all.

I dont know if there is a way to make mapView rounded;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a container view and specify the `cornerRadius` for the layer of the container view.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is shown? Have you set `masksToBounds` of the container layer to `YES`?

Comment: Thanks Ortwin i have forgotten to add masksToBounds property. it works that way.